# I can't directly save changes to a file opened through the maui app

Tags: c#, android, file, maui

My app saves documents (pdf, word...) in an external folder (documents) with permission to access all files. However, when I open a document from the app, it opens a copy of the document, which I can then save only as a copy and replace the original file with it. I would like to open the original file directly.

Code OpenDocuments (In FileInfo, enter the info of a file saved in the external storage, such as the Android Documents folder):

```
public async void OpenDocuments(FileInfo fileInfo)
 {
     try
     {
         Java.IO.File myDir = new(fileInfo.Directory.FullName);
         myDir.Mkdir();
         Java.IO.File file = new(myDir, fileInfo.Name);

         if (file.Exists())
         {
             if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
             {
                 var fileUri = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", file);
                 
                 var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
                 intent.SetData(fileUri);
                 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
                 Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
             }
             else
             {
                 var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.AbsolutePath);
                 var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                 intent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, fileInfo.Extension);
                 intent = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Open File");
                 intent!.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                 Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("ERRORE", ex.Message, "OK");
     }
 }
```

provider_path.xml (Put this in your Android's Resources/XML folder, if you don't have it Create the XML folder in Resources):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

provider in the android Manifest (put this in the android manifest):

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
</provider>
```

For access to external files you have to enable access to all files, I do it this way and it works:

```
private async void SetPermission()
{
    #if ANDROID
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.PackageName);
    Intent intent = new Intent(action: Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission, uri: uri);
    Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    #endif
}
```

Create folder in Android Documents external storage (this work):

```
public async void CreateFolder()
{
    bool permitted = Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager;
    if (permitted)
    {
        string documentDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath;
        string mainDir = Path.Combine(documentDir, "DocumentsMobile");
        fileCache = Directory.CreateDirectory(mainDir);
    }
}
```

Searching file in the directory, then you have to pass this info file to OpenDocuments (this work):

```
public FileInfo SearchFile(string fileName)
        var file = fileCache.GetFiles().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == fileName);
        return file;
}
```

In this way everything works for me but it opens the file as a copy of the original file and therefore I cannot save it directly in the original file but I have to save it as a copy and replace it with the original file. It's like this with all types of files and I've also tried using other applications besides the Microsoft ones such as WPS office.

Open file with word and here I don't have save but only save as copy:
[image: Open file with word]

[image: Here I don't have save but only save as copy]

**UPDATE**

Using sdk version 23 or lower this work, but it's only a workaround

```
public async void ApriFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

    string extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(fileInfo.Name);
    string mimeType = GetMimeType(extension);

    intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), mimeType);
    Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem and the full code of `OpenDocuments` ?

Comment: I added the necessary code to try, let me know if you find a solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it gives me the same problem, so I looked at the android developers site and found something that maybe can help you.

I made this code in OpenDocuments but it gives me an error when creating the fileDesc, I don't know if it's the correct method to solve the problem.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor fileDesc = new Activity().ContentResolver.OpenFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDesc.FileDescriptor);
fileOutputStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Overwritten at " + DateTime.Now + "\n"));
// Let the document provider know you're done by closing the stream.
fileOutputStream.Close();
fileDesc.Close();
```

Links I found that might be useful for solving the problem:

[Site where I got my code](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files?hl=it#edit)

[Another site I found but haven't used](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider?hl=it#openDocument)

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me the same error, so I tried to fix it but couldn't. But the links seem useful, I'll let you know if I can fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [FileSaver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/file-saver?tabs=android).

The FileSaver provides the ability to select target folder and save files to the file system.

Please refer to the following code:

```
async Task SaveFile(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello from the Community Toolkit!"));
    var fileSaverResult = await FileSaver.Default.SaveAsync("test.txt", stream, cancellationToken);
    if (fileSaverResult.IsSuccessful)
    {
        await Toast.Make($"The file was saved successfully to location: {fileSaverResult.FilePath}").Show(cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        await Toast.Make($"The file was not saved successfully with error: {fileSaverResult.Exception.Message}").Show(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can wait for the file to close to call the SaveFile method? I'm trying with the OnRestart method in android's mainactivity but this way it's called every time the app is paused. Thanks for the help

Comment: `I'm trying with the OnRestart method in android's mainactivity`  What exactly did you do in Method `OnRestart `? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I was able to try it but it doesn't solve my problem because it doesn't automatically save the changes made to the file.

Comment: What do you mean by words `it doesn't automatically save the changes` ? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'll give you an example with a word file, I would like to open the word file through the app and I was able to do this through the android intents, but when I'm inside Word and I click on save I get "save a copy" because the file opened by my app is not the real file but a copy of the file. Basically when I open the file the app sees that the file exists, it creates a copy of the file without path (I think it creates it in the cache of the app in which I open it) and therefore I can't save the file directly in Word, since if I click on save (in word) it comes out save as copy.